# How can I capture video from webcam in julia?

Tags: video, julia, webcam

I want to capture video from webcam, and save file in my computer.

I did it in Python. But how it do in Julia, and don't use "PyCall". Thanks.

This is my code in Python:

```
from ffmpy import FFmpeg

ff=FFmpeg(
    inputs={"rtsp://......@.....":None},
    outputs={'./Video.mp4':'-t 00:01:00'})

print(ff.cmd)
ff.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ffmpy` just run an external `ffmpeg` program. You can do the same in Julia with the usual [mechanisms](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/). I wasn't able to reproduce rtsp example, but according to [ffmpeg docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam) one can use something like `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv`, which in julia can be written as

```
run(`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv`)
```

I think it can be adapted to rtsp straightforwardly.

Also you can use [FFMPEG.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/FFMPEG.jl) which basically does the same, but it adds some convinience wrappers.

```
using FFMPEG

FFMPEG.exe("-f", "v4l2", "-framerate", "25", "-video_size", "640x480", "-i", "/dev/video0", "output.mkv")
```

Comment: OK! Thank you so much.